# Difficulty in understanding the following css syntax

Tags: css

Currently i have a css snippet as follows:

```
ul.grid, ul.grid > li {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
list-style-type: none;
}
```

can someone explain to me what is meant by

```
ul.grid, ul.grid > li ?
```

Correct me if i am wrong, `ul.grid` says that grid is a class? Can i some how use id instead of class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ul.grid` means a `ul` element with class `grid`.

`ul.grid > li` means an `li` element which is a direct child (and not a further descendant) of a `ul` element with class `grid`.

The comma separating the two means that the following rules will be applied to elements matching both selectors, so in other words, they will be applied to the `ul` and all of its children `li` elements.

> Can i some how use id instead of class?

Yes. Replace the `.` with a `#` and make sure the elements have an `id`:

`ul#grid, ul#grid > li { ... }`

That would apply to, for example:

```
<ul id="grid">
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use ID instead of class, replace the `.` with a `#` and use the `ul` ID:

```
ul#ulID, ul#ulID > li
```

Answer (score 0):

ul.grid means any ul tag which also has a class of grid.
ul.grid > li represents any li tag which is a child of a ul tag which has a class of grid.